# How to send output of shell command to client in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to send output of shell command to client.

Here is the code snippet which handles POST request:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {

    console.log("request is received");
    const ps = spawn('sh', ['test.sh', req.body.code]);
    ps.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });

    ps.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    ps.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    });

    // echo incoming data to test whether POST request works
    res.status(200).json({ myReply: req.body.code });

});
```

How can I send stdout to client in such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it should be noted that what you about to do is dangerous. Very dangerous.

Blindly executing a command from a client is not wise, you should sanitize both your ingress and egress data from untrusted sources.

While I am indeed making an assumption that this is not happening based on your provided example I just firmly believe you should rethink your design if this is the case.

Now that I have spoken up you should capture `stdout` to any array or object during the `on('data', (data) => {` and send it to the client on `close`.

`let results =[];
const ps = spawn('sh', ['test.sh', req.body.code]);
    ps.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
        results.push(${data});
    });

```
ps.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ps.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    res.status(200).json(results);
});

// echo incoming data to test whether POST request works
res.status(200).json({ myReply: req.body.code });`
```

Answer (score 3):

You can stream the `stdout` from the child process back to `res`. This works because `ps.stdout` is a readable stream and `res` is a writable stream.

```
ps.stdout.pipe(res)
```

Comment: This only pipes stdout, not both stdout and stderr

Comment: So you add `ps.stderr.pipe(res)`. However, the question specifically asks for stdout at the bottom.